# How to reshape dataframe by creating a grouping multiheader from specific column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I like to reshape a `dataframe` thats first column should be used to group the other columns by an additional header row.

**Initial `dataframe`**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
        'col2':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'col3':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'col4':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'colx':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
)
```

**Trial:**
Using `pd.pivot()` I can create an example, but this do not fit my expected one, it seems to be flipped in grouping:

```
df.pivot(columns='col1', values=['col2','col3','col4','colx'])

     col2      col3      col4      colx     
col1    A    B    A    B    A    B    A    B
0     1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1     2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
2     3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN
3     NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0
4     NaN  5.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  5.0
5     NaN  6.0  NaN  6.0  NaN  6.0  NaN  6.0
```

**Expected output:**

```
        A                               B
col1    col2    col3    col4    colx    col2    col3    col4    colx
0       1       1       1       1       4       4       4       4
1       2       2       2       2       5       5       5       5
2       3       3       3       3       6       6       6       6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with swapping level of `MultiIndex in columns` by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), sorting it and last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.assign(g = df.groupby('col1').cumcount())
        .pivot(index='g', columns='col1')
        .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=[None, None]))

print(df)
     A                   B               
  col2 col3 col4 colx col2 col3 col4 colx
0    1    1    1    1    4    4    4    4
1    2    2    2    2    5    5    5    5
2    3    3    3    3    6    6    6    6
```

Comment: Great and on the point as usal. Played around with `assign()` too, but I had no idea how to proceed with the grouping. So `cumcount()` here is the key experience for me + topping of `swaplevel`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the [classical `pivot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe), you can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the output of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with a dictionary comprehension, ensuring alignment with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = pd.concat({k: d.drop(columns='col1').reset_index(drop=True)
                 for k,d in df.groupby('col1')}, axis=1)
```

output:

```
     A                   B               
  col2 col3 col4 colx col2 col3 col4 colx
0    1    1    1    1    4    4    4    4
1    2    2    2    2    5    5    5    5
2    3    3    3    3    6    6    6    6
```